# structure theorem for Banach spaces

Tags: functional-analysis

The following is a theorem in the *Banach Algebra Techniques in Operator Theory* by Douglas:

[image]

Here are my **questions**:

- Could one come up with some reference (or proof) regarding the remark right after the proof:

> if $\mathscr{X}$ is separable, then $X$ can be taken into the closed unit interval $[0,1]$?

- Why does the remark say that the *canonical* $X$ associated with $\mathscr{X}$ is absent? Isn't it $(\mathscr{X}^*)_1$ (the closed unit ball in $\mathscr{X}^*$)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is [the Banach–Mazur theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach%E2%80%93Mazur_theorem).

When $X$ is separable, [the unit ball $B_{X^*}$ of $X^*$ is metrisable in the weak*-topology](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/27441/17929). [Every compact metric space is a continuous image of the Cantor set $\Delta$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1970/17929) Thus $X$ can be regarded as a subspace of $C(B_{X^{*}})$ which in turn is a subspace of $C(\Delta)$ via $$\iota(f) = f\circ \varphi\quad \big(f\in C(B_{X^*})\big)$$ where $\varphi \colon \Delta \to B_{X^*}$ is a continuous surjection. Now it is enough to embed $C(\Delta)$ isometrically into $C[0,1]$. Usually people use the Borsuk(–Dugundji) theorem to find such an embedding.

This theorem asserts that if $K$ is a compact Hausdorff space and $L$ is a closed, metrisable subspace of $K$ then there exists a norm-one operator $T\colon C(L)\to C(K)$ such that $(Tf)|_L = f$ for all $f\in C(L)$.

There are many ways to embed $C(\Delta)$ into $C[0,1]$ and there is no canonical surjection $\varphi \colon \Delta\to B_{X^*}$ either so that is why the adjective *canonical* is omitted.